# Asp.net Dropdownlist selected Index not firing when using with jQuery ui select menu

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

When I am using jQuery-UI Select menu on a dropdownlist and trying to call `selectedindexchanged` event it is not firing, where else if I removed jQuery  function of `select menu` from dropdownlist it is working fine.

I could not sort out and need help here.

My implementation is as

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlProjects" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control ddlStyle" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProjects_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

jQuery call is as:

```
$('#<%= ddlProjects.ClientID%>').selectmenu().selectmenu("menuWidget").addClass("overflow");
```

and code behind is

```
 protected void ddlProjectToMapped_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           if(ddlProjectToMapped.SelectedIndex==0)
           {
               divUsersAlreadyMap.Visible = false;
               CloseDivs();
           }
           else
           {
               string selectedItemValue = ddlProjectToMapped.SelectedItem.Value;
               LoadDataInLstUserAlreadyMapped(selectedItemValue);
               OpenControls();
           }
       }
```

Note that: This function is working fine when jQuery select menu function call is removed

Answer (score 2):

selectmenu transforms the select into a custom control. Probably you need to hook on change event on selectmenu and then trigger the postback from there.

```
$('#<%= ddlProjects.ClientID%>').selectmenu(change: function( event, ui ) {

__doPostBack($(this), '');

}).selectmenu("menuWidget").addClass("overflow");
```

Comment: I hit the same issue in migrating from old (legacy) jQueryUI with SelectMenu plugin to the "built in" jQueryUI selectMenu.Fix was as this answer, with a minor mod:

    if ($(this).attr('onchange'))
    {
        __doPostBack($(this).attr('name'), '')
     }

Answer (score 1):

First check if there is a "onchange" attribute.
If no attribute -> regular selectmenu(...)
if onchange attribute -> selectmenu() with "change function" wich execute the code. (__doPostBack or whatever)

```
$('select').each(function(){
            var onchg=$(this).attr('onchange');
            if(onchg==undefined){$(this).selectmenu()}
            else{$(this).selectmenu({change:function(){eval(onchg)}});
        });
```